# Which environment variable to use for filepath?

Tags: vbscript, environment-variables

I want to assign a variable to a filepath located in the 'Users' folder in the C: Drive. This filepath is different for each user, but I can't figure out exactly which environment variable to use, and how to use it with VBScript.

Example Code:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("USER")

'The folder where to save the file:
strFolder = "C:\Users\" & wshSystemEnv & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns"
```

So how do I use the `wshSystemEnv` variable in the filepath, and is it even the right variable?

The error that pops up for the `strFolder` line is

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Comment: Use `wshSystemEnv = ...` instead of `Set wshSystemEnv = ...`, you assigning a string, not an object.

Comment: @omegastripes No. The [`Environment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) property returns [`WshEnvironment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6s7w15a0%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) objects. You're probably thinking of the [`ExpandEnvironmentStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8116cf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

Comment: Oh my bad! @AnsgarWiechers you are right indeed!

Comment: Don't use `wshShell.Environment("USER")` since it doesn't contain an item with username.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `%APPDATA%` environment variable:

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

appData = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%APPDATA%")

strFolder = fso.BuildPath(appData, "Microsoft\AddIns")
```

Always build your paths using the [`BuildPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method.

---

The error you're getting from your code is because `wshSystemEnv` is an object and cannot be concatenated with strings like that.

---

The environment variable `%APPDATA%` traditionally points to the application data folder in the user's (roaming) profile. Since Windows Vista Microsoft split that folder into [three subfolders](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/what-appdata-folder) only one of which remains part of roaming profiles (`AppData\Roaming`). The other 2 remain local mainly for synchronization performance reasons.

The reason why `%APPDATA%` points to the `Roaming` subfolder instead of `%USERPROFILE%\AppData` is most likely that having it point to the parent folder would have required a lot of application vendors to release updates with modified paths due to the additional level of hierarchy (`%APPDATA%\application\foo` to `%APPDATA%\Roaming\application\foo`).

Comment: I'm grateful for all the help, your solution worked. At first I added "Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns" to the last line of code, and was getting a filepath error. Can you explain why the &APPDATA& takes me one level deeper than expected?

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate environment variable is "USERNAME".

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshSystemEnv = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
strFolder = "C:\Users\" & wshSystemEnv & "\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns"
```

or you can also use:

```
wshSystemEnv = wshShell.Environment("PROCESS").Item("USERNAME")
```

Just Google VBScript environment variable and you'll get lots of examples and references.

Comment: The error box for your code says "Object required: '[string: "b012918"]' " and the b012918 is my username

Comment: Yes--as the other comment on your question states, you need to remove the SET from the second line.  SET should be used when you are creating an object, but not if you're just assigning something to a variable.  I reproduced your "Object required" error by putting Set on that line like you have it in the question.